# On simple integer solutions of $2^{(yp-2)/(p-2)!}=px+1,$ where $p$ is a fixed prime $\equiv 1\text{ mod }4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, congruences

I am interested in to know how to find integer solutions $(x,y)$, with $x,y\geq 1$ of $$2^{\frac{yp-2}{(p-2)!}}=px+1,$$ where $p$ is a fixed prime satisfying $p\equiv 1\text{ mod }4$. You can read, if you want, the motivation of next questions below.

> **Question 1.** Can you provide me a simple example of solution $(x,y)$, where $x\geq 1$ and $y\geq 1$ are integers of $$2^{\frac{5y-2}{6}}=5x+1?$$ Preferably I would like to know your reasoning to find such simple example.

If there are no mistakes I've discard the first few cases. Additionally I propose another similar problem, for a different prime number.

> **Question 2.** Can you provide me a simple example of solution $(x,y)$, where $x\geq 1$ and $y\geq 1$ are integers of $$2^{\frac{13y-2}{11!}}=13x+1?$$ **Thanks you so much.**

*Motivation.* We assume that there exists an odd perfect number $n=p^{4\lambda+1}m^2$, here $p\equiv 1\text{ mod }4$ is prime satisfying $(p,m)=1$. Since $n$ is perfect one has $$2(p-1)=\frac{p^{4\lambda+2}-1}{n}\sigma(m^2):=Q.\tag{1}$$ Previous identity combined with Fermat's little theorem implies that there exist a positive integer $x\geq 1$ such that $$2^Q=xp+1.\tag{2}$$
On the other hand we multiply the identity $(1)$ by $(p-2)!$ to get $$2(p-1)!=Q(p-2)!,$$ then Wilson-Lagrange theorem implies that there exists a positive integer $y\geq 1$ such that $$Q(p-2)!=yp-2.\tag{3}$$
Then for a fixed prime $p$, and we're interested in primes of the form $p\equiv 1\text{ mod }4$, one has from $(2)$ and $(3)$ that there exist positive integers $x,y\geq 1$ such that $$2^{(yp-2)/(p-2)!}=px+1.$$

Comment: $2^a \equiv 1 \bmod p$ iff $a$ divides the order $ord(2 \bmod p)$, ie. the least positive integer such that $2^b \equiv 1 \bmod p$. The Fermat little theorem is a consequence of $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ being a group with $p-1$ elements, so that $ord(a \bmod p) \ | \ p-1$. More generally $ord(a \bmod n) \ | \ \phi(n)$ if $gcd(n,a)=1$.

Comment: Many thanks @reuns now I see with your hints that is easy how to find a solution of Question 1: from $$\frac{py-2}{(p-2)!}\mid p-1$$ then one finds $y=10$, and from this $2^8=5x+1$ and tus $x=51$. I am waiting if some user wants to answer Question 2 using this method or add more examples.

Comment: So are you capable to prove everything, and what is the answer ?

Comment: Good morning I did not say it. Add your comment as an answer, if you want, with examples for Question 2, this is appreciated @reuns

Comment: I told you 50 times I won't write an answer. Where are you stuck ? Can you stop with those useless comments ?

Comment: No problem, then my apologizes @reuns

Comment: lol. My question was "were are you stuck" ?